# Add style to custom label depending on boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

I want to add a style to a label (custom class, which inherit label) depending on a boolean, highlighted, in the custom class. I want it to remove the style if the boolean is false else add the style. This variable is changed throughout the application.

(style: SelectedBackground)

```
<local:unit xPos="13" yPos="1" Grid.Row="{Binding yPos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Grid.Column="{Binding xPos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Unit:

```
    public class Unit : Label, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public Unit() { } //Grass
        public Unit(int x, int y)
        {
            this.xPos = x;
            this.yPos = y;
        }

        public static readonly RoutedEvent ClickEvent;

        private int _xPos, _yPos;

        public bool _highlighted = false;
        public bool highlighted 
        {
            get { return _highlighted; }
            set {
                _highlighted = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("highlighted");
            }
        }   

        public bool mouseLeft
        {
            get { return _mouseLeft; }
            set
            {
                _mouseLeft = value;
            }
        }
        public bool mouseRight
        {
            get { return _mouseRight; }
            set
            {
                _mouseRight = value;
            }
        }

        public int xPos
        {
            get { return _xPos; }
            set
            {
                _xPos = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("xPos");
            }
        }
        public int yPos
        {
            get { return _yPos; }
            set
            {
                _yPos = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("yPos");
            }
        }

        private string _type = "none";
        public string type
        {
            get { return _type; }
            set
            {
                _type = value;
            }

        }


        static Unit()
        {
            ClickEvent = ButtonBase.ClickEvent.AddOwner(typeof(Unit));
        }



        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("property changed");

                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: You could try using an IValueConverter to convert the bool to the styles you've selected. You could also use any other type, if you ever want to have more than two styles. I like to swap the resource dictionaries in and out to change themes.

Comment: Sounds promising. Could you give me an example? I am new to this!

Comment: Your code is all wrong. Delete all that. You must NOT implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in a `DependencyObject`. Please read the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025(v=vs.110).aspx) on how to create controls in WPF.

Comment: Converter bindings are fairly easy to do in wpf, since you mostly just implement the IValueConverter interface and then make sure to add an instance to the view's resource dictionary. Then you can do `Style="{Binding whateverBool, Converter={StaticResource theConverterKey}}"` As for swapping resource dictionaries, SO has other answers for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply a style with a data trigger which is binded to the property flag in the view model.

here is the xaml:

```
<wpfApp:CustomLabel>
     <wpfApp:CustomLabel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpfApp:CustomLabel}">
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ApplyStyleToLabel}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                <!-- Specify the remaining property setters here -->
             </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
     </wpfApp:CustomLabel.Style>
 </wpfApp:CustomLabel>
```

You should specify the remaining setters in the given location. In a way, the changes you wish to make thru style will only be applicable to the label when the property is true. you can also use its own property to bind in the data trigger.

You need not derive your control from INotifyPropertyChanged
for a dependency property created in the control here will be your xaml

```
<wpfApp:CustomLabel>
            <wpfApp:CustomLabel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type wpfApp:CustomLabel}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ApplyStyle" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
         </wpfApp:CustomLabel.Style>
 </wpfApp:CustomLabel>
```

Control class is as follows:

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{


    public bool ApplyStyle
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ApplyStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ApplyStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ApplyStyle.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ApplyStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ApplyStyle", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomLabel), new PropertyMetadata(false));


}
```

Read more about creating dependency property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
This should give you an idea about the metadata to be specified in dp creation

Hope it helps